# when and otherwise in pyspark using independent conditions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to make a new column based on list of items. cond is a separate independent list outside dataframe "ABC". A new column needs to be created based on few conditions, please see a dummy condition below:-

```
Rules = ['2'. '5', '18', '33', '47']

ABC = ABC.withColumn("XYZ", when ('2' in cond), col("sqr_4231"))\
                                   .when(('3' in cond), col("sqr_4999"))
```

but this is giving error - have `tried lit('2')` and `lit('3')` but still giving error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To verify if a value contains in an array you need to use:

```py
lit('value').isin(array_value)
```

```py
aggregate = aggregate.withColumn("ENR", when(lit('2').isin(Rules), col("sqr_4231"))\
                                   .when(lit('3').isin(Rules), col("sqr_4999"))
```